# Dart web application can not import local package

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have developed a simple library (called picasawebalbums) that I wish to import in another web application.

I have added the the following to pubspect.yaml

```
  picasawebalbums:
    path: C:\Users\hangs_000\Documents\GitHub\PicasaWebAlbums
```

But the package does not appear under the 'packages' directory and of course my dart code cannot import any of the classes.

I feel that I have missed out a step somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pub get --verbose` or `pub upgrade --verbose` from command line in your application directory and look at the output. You can try without `--verbose` first. This prints much less but may offer a hint anywhere.